# Angular 8 - child routerLink doesn't work

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router, routerlink

I want to navigate from one page to another, from one component to another:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UploadPageComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'frameworks',
        component: FrameworksSceneComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full',
        children: [
          {//doesn't work
            path: 'questionnaire',
            component: QuestionnaireComponent,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: 'documents',
        component: DocumentsSceneComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {//works
        path: 'questionnaire',
        component: QuestionnaireComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class UploadRoutingModule {
}
```

My template (FrameworksSceneComponent):

```
 <a [routerLink]="['questionnaire']">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
```

but this works (FrameworksSceneComponent):

```
<a [routerLink]="['/private/upload/questionnaire']">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</a>
```

What's wrong with my nested links? WHy after clicking on `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` I'm redirected to my main page. ON the other hand  link `bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb` works, but in thus case the link is not a child link.

Comment: <a [routerLink]="['questionnaire']">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a> are you calling this on /framwork route ?

Comment: Ye, I'm calling aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa in FrameworksSceneComponent component (in template)... I edited my post by adding FrameworksSceneComponent as the component from which I want to navigate to QuestionnaireComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you implemented the nested route, angular looking for a `<router-outlet>` in your `FrameworksSceneComponent.html`. try implementing like below. not sure why its navigate to the main page.

```
  routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: "",
      children: [
        {
          path: "",
          component: UploadPageComponent
        },
        {
          path: "frameworks",
          children: [
            {
              path: "",
              component: FrameworksSceneComponent,
              pathMatch: "full"
            },
            {
              //should  work
              path: "questionnaire",
              component: QuestionnaireComponent
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          path: "documents",
          component: DocumentsSceneComponent,
          pathMatch: "full"
        },
        {
          //works
          path: "questionnaire",
          component: QuestionnaireComponent,
          pathMatch: "full"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Comment: Hmm I have menu structure like upload -> then 2 subtabs/2 submenus: Documents and Frameworks. And under Frameworks I'd like to have additional Questionnaire page with the link upload/frameworks/questionnaire